# How to prove that the volume of a solid $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is $\iiint\limits_S \;\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How to prove that the volume of a solid $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is

$$\iiint\limits_S \;\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

Comment: To me, this is the definition of volume. How are you defining volume?

Comment: Don't you define $$\text{vol}(A) = \iiint\limits_{A} \, dV = \iiint\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} \chi_{A} \, dV?$$

Comment: it is a definition?

Comment: @Jarbas: well, if it isn't, then you need to compare it to some other definition. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Definition: Let $S$ a region of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $vol(S)=\alpha$ if $vol(P) \leq \alpha \leq vol(Q)$, for all $P$ and $Q$, rectangular polyhedra that are contained and contains $S$ respectively.